# Is there a way to rollback edited kubernetes manifest file?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

Pod with some values was deployed, then I edited it `kubectl edit pod <pod>`, and now wanted to get back to the previous state (no longer have the values as someone else deployed it some time ago). Is it possible?

And second question.
If someone deployed to GKE cluster with helm, is it possible (even though I have access to cluster and can see all `kubectl get all`) that I don't see those deployments with `helm list` but see the kubernetes pods ? - rephrasing it. Is it possible someone deployed to cluster with helm and I only see pods, no helm config with `helm list` ?

ps: helm and kubernetes works fine with other clusters or minikube:

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

````
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-13T11:51:44Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.11-gke.14", GitCommit:"56d89863d1033f9668ddd6e1c1aea81cd846ef88", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-07T19:12:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.11b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}```
````

Comment: Do you see tiller pod in your cluster and any error in tiller pod logs?

Comment: "helm ls # If you receive an error that Helm could not find a ready tiller pod, it means that helm is still deploying. [Wait a few moments for the tiller Docker Image to finish downloading](https://wilsonmar.github.io/helm/)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pods does not have rollback feature that's why you should use [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) which provides [rollback functionality](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-a-deployment). Also good practice for production is to version control your yamls for easy rollback and audit.